# How to copy chart from an excel file to power point?

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.0, office-interop

I have a C# code building an excel file containing few charts. I'm working with Excel through `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` 12.

That's working fine but at the same time I need to generate a PowerPoint presentation containing the same exact charts.

Is there any way to copy 
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject` to PowerPoint file? Or any other way to copy those charts in to PowerPoint presentation programmatically?

Comment: You can build the charts directly in to powerpoint with VBA, using most (almost all) of the same methods available in Excel.  Unless you *need* the charts in an Excel workbook for some other reason.

Comment: I realize it's not an optimal solution to copy objects between 2 different applications but since I need to give user a choice if he wants this chart it Excel or PowerPoint, or even both at the same time I see no point to write separate logic for PowerPoint when there is already one for Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this should work

```
            using xlNS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
            using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

            xlNS.ApplicationClass excelApplication = null;
            xlNS.Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
            xlNS.Worksheet targetSheet = null;
            xlNS.ChartObjects chartObjects = null;
            xlNS.ChartObject existingChartObject = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange shapeRange = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide CurSlide;


            excelApplication = new xlNS.ApplicationClass();//Create New Excel
            excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(Excelpath,
                 paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                 paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                 paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing);

            Ws = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets[6];//Your Sheet that contain Chart
            Ws.Activate();
            targetSheet = (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets["SheetName"]);
            chartObjects = (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));
            existingChartObject = (xlNS.ChartObject)(chartObjects.Item(1));

            existingChartObject.Copy();
            shapeRange = CurSlide.Shapes.Paste();//Paste it to your Current Slide
            shapeRange.Left = 435;
            shapeRange.Top = 80; //Formatting your chart
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example. For some reason I thought it will be harder than just simple copy-paste.